# Inconsistent RGBA across devices

Tags: ios, css, colors, cross-browser

If you make a simple website with the code:

```
<div style='background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.05);width:50px;height:50px'></div>
```

and view it on various devices, you'll see very different colors.

On my iPhone and iPad, it looks white but on my MacBook you can see a definite light grey that looks close to `#fafafa`; I haven't tested thoroughly on other devices but I think that Android Chrome will sometimes display a third in between color.

This isn't an issue of different screen color capacities, because the iPad is definitely capable of displaying #fafafa.

So what's the story and is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Metameric Failure. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamerism_(color). Each screen has a different spectral distribution, so they can measure the same, but be perceptively different. Example: Walk into a electronics retailer, every brand of TV with different back lights can look wildly different sitting next to each other displaying content you know to be identical.

Comment: But as I said, I'm concerned more about the difference between the `#fafafa` and `rgba(0,0,0,.05)` than between different devices.

Comment: Are you trying to match `#fafafa` to `rgba(0,0,0,0.5)` ? Now I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rgba(0,0,0,.05)` is an incredibly light color. A 5% tint is not visible on many lower end LCDs - especially [6bit panels](http://www.tftcentral.co.uk/articles/content/6bit_8bit.htm). Personally, when I use RGBA I only tweak by 10% increments. Also, you will notice that `#fafafa` and `rgba(0,0,0,.05)` don't display the same because they aren't the same. `#f2f2f2` is `rgba(0,0,0,.05)` (at least in Photoshop.)

You also have variances between the type of RGB. Devices also adapt differently based on lighting conditions - and they don't adapt the same way. There's also different [screen types](http://www.tftcentral.co.uk/specs.htm) like [AMOLED](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMOLED)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience that normally happens because of the contrast on the different screens and brightness settings. My suggestion is play with those.

Also check this for browser compatibility but those you mentioned should be ok:

http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/